# How to successfully complete this INSERT JOIN WHERE SQL statement?

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to insert into table community_players the community_id and player_id from respective tables; 'communities' and 'users' where the following conditions are met:

users.user_email AND communities.admin = 'steve.downs@gmail.com'
AND
communities.code = 'HX99F9'

This is what I have so far....

`INSERT INTO TABLE community_players (community_id, player_id)
FROM TABLE communities
JOIN TABLE users
ON id
WHERE users.user_email = 'steve.downs@gmail.com'
AND communities.admin = 'steve.downs@gmail.com'
AND communities.code = 'HX99f9'`

These are the 3 tables in question:

`users
id | user_email | user_password | user_name`

`communities
id | name | code | admin`

`community_players
community_id | player_id`

Comment: Could you please add the structure of your tables? We can only ques how the fields in your tables are called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO community_players (community_id, player_id)
SELECT communities.id, users.id
FROM communities INNER JOIN users ON communities.admin = users.user_email
WHERE users.user_email = 'steve.downs@gmail.com'
AND communities.code = 'HX99f9'
```

Comment: That is producing the following error;:  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TABLE communities
JOIN TABLE users ON communities.admin = users.user_email
WHE' at line 3

Comment: That's great that has fixed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like:

`INSERT INTO community_players (community_id, player_id)
(SELECT communities.community_id, users.user_id
FROM TABLE communities
JOIN TABLE users ON id
WHERE users.user_email = 'steve.downs@gmail.com'
AND communities.admin = 'steve.downs@gmail.com'
AND communities.code = 'HX99f9'`
)`

But its hard to say, without knowing the database schemas of the tables communities and users. Which sounds particular weird is the `JOIN TABLE users ON id` part ... this will only work, if the communities table has a field which holds the user id (which might be uncommon in that use case).

Comment: Ok, can you show the Database Schema please? Without them its hard to help, because nobody knows how the database fields are named